# How can I add a default header to my source files automatically in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a comment header automatically added to all new source files in my eclipse java project. I've looked around but I haven't found a simple solution to automate this process. I gave JAutodoc a try, and even though it does allow me to specify a header I still had to tell the plugin manually to inject the header and it didn't seem very fond of my keyword-subsitution.

I'm by the way using the Maven2 plugin for Eclipse for most of my projects if that's any help.

Any tips?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Comments generation is configured in:

**Main Menu** -> **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Code Style** -> **Code Templates** -> **Configure generated code and comments**

You can change directly the New Java files template:
**Code** -> **New Java files** -> **Edit**

As of Eclipse 3.6 version, it is already configured that for new Java files `${filecomment}` is inserted, so it is probably better to edit it instead:

**Comments** -> **Files** -> **Edit**

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do the trick. I'll take a closer look at, I should be able to figure it out now that I've got directions.

Comment: I had to also check the `Automatically add comments for new methods and types` option to make it work.

Comment: As jeremija said, this answer should be edited to include that "Automatically add comments for new methods and types"

Answer (score 17):

If you want to add your comment a the top of the file (to add a copyright header), give a try to [Eclipse Copyright Generator](https://jmini.github.io/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/). There is a wizard that ask you what you want to include. Therefore you can add every kind of comment header.

After installation you get a new menu: **Project > Apply Copyright...**.

In the **include files** field enter `*.java` to reduce the set of files.

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105664/adding-a-standard-comment-header-to-all-source-files-in-eclipse/5491932#5491932)

---

As indicated in the comments, there is an other tool provided by the Eclipse Fundation: [Eclipse Copyright Tool](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool) (as part of their releng tools)

Comment: Eclipse Copyright Generator works for existing files.  The accepted answer works for newly created files.

Comment: Eclipse Copyright Generator seems to not work with php files.

Comment: I have publised a new version on Github/Bintray: https://jmini.github.io/Eclipse-Copyright-Generator/

Comment: The new name is "releng tools". https://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/How_to_Use_Eclipse_Copyright_Tool