# Trying to cat a header into source files but a Unicode BOM is getting in the way

Tags: header, byte-order-mark, cat

Following the instructions at [Add header (copyright) information to existing source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436792/add-headercopyright-information-to-existing-source-files), I need to add copyright headers to a bunch of source files we're sending out of the building. (I know, I hate copyright headers too, but it's policy for when we release proprietary source files. Please consider "persuade someone to waive the policy" as unhelpful and as not answering the question.)

I have two copies of all the files (in `dir` and `dir.orig`) and, from within `dir.orig`, I'm using

```
find . -name \*.cs -exec sh -c "mv '{}' tmp && cp ../header.txt '../dir/{}'
  && cat tmp >> '../dir/{}' && rm tmp" \;
```

This is working, but it's ending up with the header, then the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) from the original source file, whereas I'd prefer either the BOM to move to the start or be removed.

(Looking at this, I realise that moving the file to `tmp` is unnecessary, given I'm not overwriting the original, but I didn't bother removing that from the example from the other SO question.)

How can I remove (or move) the BOM so that I end up without it appearing immediately after the newly-added header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found my solution, thanks to being pointed to [`uconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3293858/205245) from [Steven R. Loomis](/users/185799/steven-r-loomis) on a related question.

If I use

```
find . -name *.cs -exec sh -c "cp ../header.txt '../dir/{}'
  && uconv --remove-signature -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 '{}' >> '../dir/{}'" \;
```

, then `uconv` assumes both input (`-f`) and output (`-t`) encodings should be UTF-8, but `--remove-signature` causes it to remove any BOM it finds.