# Add Copyright header to all project files (.java, .xml, ...)

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, eclipse-plugin

I have several maven projects where I'd like to add a common header (copyright information, etc.). Is there a tool, or Eclipse plugin, to do this?

A simple shell script won't do the job, because some files already have such a header - and I don't just want to blindly append another header.

So some plugin with "sophisticated" logic would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: Does [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105664/adding-a-standard-comment-header-to-all-source-files-in-eclipse) help?

Answer (score 1):

If your project supports Maven, you can use [**maven-license-plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/license-maven-plugin/)

There are **[instructions](https://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-add-license-headers-to-code.html)** how to install and use it.